# Delayed Job fails only on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, algolia

I have a simple job that runs locally (both in development and production and staging) but fails on heroku (production and staging).

The command is `DoctorLocation.reindex!` which is a method used for algolia.

The error that is thrown is `NameError: uninitialized constant DoctorProfile::Recommendation`:

```
app[worker.1]: [Worker(host:c304ffd7-6c21-4eeb-b423-d42fae5d2adb pid:4)] Job DoctorLocation.reindex! (id=70) FAILED (3 prior attempts) with NameError: uninitialized constant DoctorProfile::Recommendation
```

What is so strange is that `DoctorLocation.reindex!` is able to successfully run in the console, it is ONLY when using delayed job that it fails.

Also, note that `DoctorProfile` and `Recommendation` are two separate models which makes this error even more confusing.

UPDATE: code for doctor location model:

```
class DoctorLocation < ApplicationRecord
  include AlgoliaSearch
  include AlgoliaDelayedJob

  belongs_to :doctor_profile
  belongs_to :location

  delegate :first_name, :last_name, :name, :photo_url, :gender, :practice, to: :doctor_profile

  unless Rails.env.test?
    algoliasearch :per_environment => true, if: :approved?,
                  id: :uuid, enqueue: :trigger_delayed_job do
      attribute :id, :uuid, :first_name, :last_name, :name, :photo_url, :gender,
                :practice, :location
      attribute :doctor_id do
        doctor_profile.id
      end

      attribute :patients do
        doctor_profile.patients.map{|x| {
          uuid: x.uuid, photo_url: x.photo_url, first_name: x.first_name,
          last_name: x.last_name, name: x.name, id: x.id
        }}
      end
      attribute :reviews do
        doctor_profile.reviews.map{|x| {
          body: x.body,
          patient_profile_photo_url: x.patient_profile.photo_url,
          patient_profile_uuid: x.patient_profile.uuid,
          patient_profile_id: x.patient_profile.id,
          patient_profile_name: x.patient_profile.name
        }}
      end
      attribute :patient_count do
        doctor_profile.patients.length
      end
      attribute :patient_ids do
        doctor_profile.patients.map(&:uuid)
      end
      attribute :insurances do
        doctor_profile.insurance_providers.map{|x| "#{x.category}:#{x.name}"}
      end
      attribute :specialties do
        doctor_profile.specialties.map(&:name)
      end
      geoloc :lat, :lon

      tags do
        doctor_profile.specialties.map(&:name)
      end

      attribute :group_ids do
        doctor_profile.patients.map{|x| x.group_ids }.flatten.compact.uniq
      end

      attribute :liked_by_friends_of_user_id do
        doctor_profile.patients.map{ |x|x.friend_ids }.flatten.compact.uniq
      end

      attributesToIndex ['first_name', 'last_name', 'name']
      attributesForFaceting [
        :insurances, :gender, :patient_ids, :liked_by_friends_of_user_id,
        :group_ids
      ]
      customRanking ['desc(patient_count)']
    end
  end

  private

  def approved?
    doctor_profile.approved
  end

  def lat
    location.latitude
  end

  def lon
    location.longitude
  end

end
```

## AlgoliaDelayedJob

```
module AlgoliaDelayedJob
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def trigger_delayed_job(record, remove)
      if remove
        # record not saved, so delete from index by id
        # (can't instantiate the model and call .delay.remove_from_index!)
        index = Algolia::Index.new("#{self.name}_#{Rails.env}")
        index.delete_object(record.uuid)
      else
        obj = self.find(record.id)
        obj.index!
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your `DoctorLocation` model?

Comment: @DanielWestendorf added the full model...a bit messy with the algolia stuff...

Comment: is there code for the #reindex! method? or is that part of the algolia gem/module?

Comment: It sounds like this is a namespacing issue - it's clearly trying to find the Recommendation model in the DoctorProfile namespace.

Comment: @DannyY part of the algolia gem https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-rails

Comment: @oowowaee agreed. any idea why a namespacing issue would be happening when deployed the heroku and not locally? does that make any sense? what settings could trigger that?

Comment: we might need to see your folder layout for those models and delayedjob workers :)

Comment: @user2954587 I would guess it is tied to autoloading.  The issue is the error message isn't that informative - it's not clear which reference to Recommendation is failing to be looked up properly (and I don't see it in your code).  You can try looking for those references and specifically telling it to use ::Recommendation and see if that fixes it.  I would also then suspect it's not tied to Heroku per se, but the order the files are being loaded.  You really can't reproduce locally in production mode?

Comment: @oowowaee thanks for the nudge in the right direction. The issue was that my recommendation model was name `Recommendation.rb`. Renaming it to `recommendation.rb` fixed the issue...